# Comparator.comparing().reversed() reverses all the earlier comparators?

Tags: java, list, sorting, comparator

I have a list of Triple which is an user-defined class. When I sort it using `Comparator` it shows weird behavior.

> Consider this snippet -

```
List<Triple> list = new ArrayList<>();
list.add(new Triple(1,12,13)); //adding values to list
list.add(new Triple(11,3,31));
list.add(new Triple(16,6,32));
list.add(new Triple(16,8,32));
list.add(new Triple(16,7,32));
list.add(new Triple(16,9,32));
list.add(new Triple(16,5,32));
list.add(new Triple(7,21,0));
list.add(new Triple(6,22,12));
list.add(new Triple(4,22,13));
list.add(new Triple(2,77,3));
list.add(new Triple(1,8,30));
```

> Sort Using Comparator

```
 list.sort(
 Comparator.comparingInt(Triple::getA)
.thenComparingInt(Triple::getB)
.thenComparing(Triple::getC));
 list.forEach(e->System.out.printf("(%d,%d,%d) ",e.getA(),e.getB(),e.getC()));
 System.out.println();
//sort A descending if for same A ascending B and for same B ascending C
 list.sort(
Comparator.comparingInt(Triple::getA).reversed()
.thenComparingInt(Triple::getB)
.thenComparing(Triple::getC));
 list.forEach(e->System.out.printf("(%d,%d,%d) ",e.getA(),e.getB(),e.getC()));
 System.out.println();
//sort A ascending if for same A descending B and for same B ascending C
list.sort(
Comparator.comparingInt(Triple::getA)
.thenComparingInt(Triple::getB)
.reversed()
.thenComparing(Triple::getC));
list.forEach(e->System.out.printf("(%d,%d,%d) ",e.getA(),e.getB(),e.getC()));
System.out.println();
//sort A ascending if for same A ascending B and for same B descending C
list.sort(
Comparator.comparingInt(Triple::getA)
.thenComparingInt(Triple::getB)
.thenComparing(Triple::getC)
.reversed());
list.forEach(e->System.out.printf("(%d,%d,%d) ",e.getA(),e.getB(),e.getC()));
```

I expect the output as the list as I stated in comments -

> ### But the output is

```
(16,5,32) (16,6,32) (16,7,32) (16,8,32) (16,9,32) (11,3,31) (7,21,0) (6,22,12) (4,22,13) (2,77,3) (1,8,30) (1,12,13)

(16,9,32) (16,8,32) (16,7,32) (16,6,32) (16,5,32) (11,3,31) (7,21,0) (6,22,12) (4,22,13) (2,77,3) (1,12,13) (1,8,30)

(16,9,32) (16,8,32) (16,7,32) (16,6,32) (16,5,32) (11,3,31) (7,21,0) (6,22,12) (4,22,13) (2,77,3) (1,12,13) (1,8,30)
```

### So reversed() method reversed the earlier comparator conditions.

For your information, Triple is just class with Three variables and get set methods.

Comment: Of course. thenComparing() returns a Comparator. This comparator defines an order. And .reversed() returns another comparator, defining the reverse order of the comparator on which it's applied.

Comment: If you want to reverse only the last comparator of the chain, then reverse only that comparator: `thenComparing(Comparator.comparing(Triple::getC).reversed())`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since you define a comparator like `Comparator.comparingInt(Triple::getA)
.thenComparingInt(Triple::getB)` this returns a new `Comparator` object that contains both previous ways of comparing the object. If you then call `reversed` on this `Comparator` it returns new Comparator which reverses this `Comparator` - so in this case both previous conditions will be reversed.

If you want to reverse one of your comparators in the chain you can use something like :

```
.thenComparing(Triple::getB, Comparator.reverseOrder())
```

So one of your comparators can look like :

```
Comparator.comparingInt(Triple::getA)
                        .thenComparing(Triple::getB, Comparator.reverseOrder())
                        .thenComparing(Triple::getC)
```

This will only reverse B property sorting condition.

Comment: So helpful @michalk I used to do this like `Comparator.comparing(Triple::getA).reversed().thenComparing(Triple::getB).reversed()` thank you